# Schengen visa after a ban from Belgium

Tags: schengen, applications, visa-bans, albanian-citizens

I am from Albania and I was banned from Belgium before 4 years and now I finished my ban.
What should I do to re-enter in Schengen without problems?
I am a visa-free national but I need a document from Belgium proving my ban has ended to show to the authorities in my country so that they will allow me to leave.
How should I make the request to get proof that my name has been removed from the Schengen database - by post or by mail?

Comment: Apply for a visa in the usual way. However, just because your ban is ended does not mean your application will be approved.

Comment: i don"t need a visa to enter in Schengen.I am allowed to stay there for 90 from 180 days

Comment: That may be true, but with a recently expired ban typical advice is to apply for a visa. It depends on your risk appetite for getting denied entry at the border.

Comment: "By post" and "by mail" mean exactly the same thing, so I'm not sure what you're asking, there.

Comment: I see that you are not informed about Schengen Information System SIS

Answer (score 3):

Because you were banned, especially if it was recently, immigration officers will suspect that you will repeat the actions that got you banned, unless you have very good evidence that you won't. Although you don't need a visa, it would be better to apply for one.  That way, if you say no, you're sitting comfortably at home, rather than stuck in an airport in some foreign country with all your plans ruined.

If you decide not to get a visa, you should expect to be questioned in detail at the border, and you should bring with you all the documents that you would use as part of a visa application.

Comment: How to apply for a visa when I don't need one.The problem is that I need a document from them that my ban has finished to show to my state to let me go there

Comment: @erald1234 Getting a document to prove your ban is over is not what you asked in your original question. Why can’t you use the document you were issued at the time you were banned? And I still think it’s possible (likely?) that you won’t be allowed to enter visa-free. Why would they let someone enter who has previously contravened immigration laws sufficiently seriously to be banned, immediately after said ban has ended?

Comment: They didn't give me any document.Sure they will let me because they respect human rights.The problem is that the police officers of my country will not let me go unless I show them the document which proves that my name is removed from Schengen database

Comment: Nobody has the right to enter a foreign country. It is always a privilege, granted by that country. And countries are reluctant to grant that privilege to people who have abused it in the past.

Comment: @erald1234 are you sure you don't need one? Many countries require people who were subject to a ban to apply for a visa after the ban ended even if they are citizens of visa free countries.

Comment: Not for Europe countries such as Albania@jwenting

Answer (score 1):

According to this guide, you should request the information from the Belgian Privacy Protection Commission in writing by post https://edps.europa.eu/sites/edp/files/publication/16-11-07_sis_ii_guide_of_access_en.pdf#page16